# WordPress change site url name (without changing the actual url)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Say I have www.example.com/uglytext as my home page. Is there a way I can change that to www.example.com/nicetext, while still keeping uglytext as the directory name, and still actually navigating to www.example.com/uglytext behind the scenes?

My current htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mobile_dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mobile_dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I need mobile_dev to be mobile. www.mysite.com/mobile rather than www.mysite.com/mobile_dev

Answer (score 0):

In your `wp-admin`, under `Settings > General`  there are two options:

- `WordPress Address (URL)` (corresponds to `siteurl` in `wp_options` table in your database)
- `Site Address (URL)` (corresponds to `home` in the same table)

You can set `WordPress Address (URL)` to `http://www.example.com/uglytext` and `Site Address (URL)` to `http://www.example.com/nicetext` to achieve the result you want.

For more information you can check this [WordPress Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) explaining the procedure for moving core WordPress files around and maintaining URLs in more detail.

Comment: Thanks. I'm away from the site atm, but since it's an older version of WordPress, it might not have Site Address (it's from 2010). I'll definitely check it out tomorrow, though.

Comment: Would this have any interference with code using the home_url() function, though? According to the codex, "Use home_url() to get the "site address" as defined in general settings."

Comment: `home_url()` is getting the URL from the `home` option [internally](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/) so it will be consistent with the site address you have assigned. If you want to get the `siteurl` you can use [site_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) function.

Comment: By the way, I have managed to work it out on WordPress Version 2.8 (2009) by applying the steps given on the page mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Unfotunately, this did not work. When I change the site url, and then try navigating to www.example.com/nicetext, it just brings up the old desktop version of the site, and says the page can't be found. If I try www.example.com/uglytext, it brings up the new mobile version, but says page can't be found there.

Comment: I fixed it. I just changed the folder name in cpanel, updated the site and wordpress urls in the wordpress admin, and in phpmyadmin, I changed the siteurl under the options table. I also went to the general and permalinks settings pages in the wp-admin and just clicked save changes to update the permalinks (which were saving the old values).